# Migrate from springfox2 to springfox 3.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, swagger-2.0, springfox

My springboot application used springfox2. and I tried to migrate to springfox3 ("io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0"). I followed the steps at https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#example-application, the section 2.1.3. Migrating from existing 2.x version. In addition I replaced some deprecated classes (e.g. globalRequestParameters, globalResponses, schma etc), but the doc generated has a couple of issues. Anyone has doc or example?  Thanks a lot!!

Issues: server url shows localhost

swagger yaml file shows

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: api title 
  description: api description
  version: '1'
servers:
  - url: 'http://localhost:8081'
    description: Inferred Url
```

I want servers url to be my api server url instead of localhost.
I tried:

```
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
            .groupName("host url")  //if comment out this, it will retrun localhost
            .host("host url")
            ...
```

with groupName being set, this will return 404 error

Comment: What do you mean by "doc generated is far from being right"? What result do you expect and what's the actual result?

Comment: Updated, thanks @Helen